# Access keys in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, access-keys, displayattribute

I'm intending to extend the `Display` DataAnnotation attribute to hold a value for the `AccessKey` for an input field so I can use it in my own `LabelFor<>` and `TextBoxFor<>` HtmlHelper extensions, something like this:

```
[Display(Name = "User name", AccessKey = "U")]
```

Before I do, can anyone tell me if there is an existing mechanism to achieve declarative access key functionality?

If there isn't, can someone tell me how to extend the `Display` DataAnnotation attribute. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this approach will help you: [asp.net MVC extending DataAnnotions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707997/asp-net-mvc-extending-dataannotions)